# A question on resonance in case of second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question
$y''-4y'+4y=e^{2x}$

In case of the given differential equation, the complementary function would be, $CF= C_1e^{2x} + C_2xe^{2x}$.

The initial $y_p$ looking at the RHS would be $Ae^{2x}$ and hence there is a superposition with the first term. So since the root of the prior equation was $(2,2)$, single root to the multiplicity of $2$, I multiplied the given $y_p$ by $x^2$ and got $y=A x^2 e^{2x}$ and went about solving the problem.

My professor considers this technique incorrect and refuses to give me marks for the given question. Is there any mathematical way to prove the given reasoning?

Comment: Sorry my bad, edited the question. I understand that, it's the method I used to figure out yp which he considers incorrect. Is there any way I can disprove him?

Comment: What you describe here sounds perfectly fine. Sorry, but without seeing all your work and knowing your professor, it's impossible to say why he graded the way he did...

Comment: He thinks the approach I used to find the y particular during a resonance is incorrect, is there any mathematical way I can explain why it is right?

Comment: The problem with proving anything about this method is that's it's based on the idea of making an educated guess. If you took some linear combination of derivatives (LHS) of a function, and ended up with $e^{2x}$, then you had to have started with something relating to $e^{2x}$, since this function is invariant under differentiation. You know that if you choose $Ae^{2x}$, the left side will be 0 because it solves the inhomogeneous case. The same happens when you try $Axe^{2x}$. Thus, you next try $Ax^2e^{2x}$ and it works, so it must be right. $Ax^3e^{2x}$ gives you $6Axe^{2x}$ which is wrong.